How to resolve Elastic Beanstalk deployment errors

Today I tried to deploy my project to a server via Elastic Beanstalk.
But I kept getting an error.
I tried to fix this error all day today but couldn't.

The text below is the result I got from a log request.
  web[2413]: > backend@1.0.0 start
  web[2413]: > nodemon index.ts
  web[2479]: sh: line 1: nodemon: command not found
  web[2484]: > backend@1.0.0 start
  web[2484]: > nodemon index.ts
  web[2502]: sh: line 1: nodemon: command not found

This is package.json code. I'm using TypeScript.
    {
      "name": "backend",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.ts",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon index.ts"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.569.0",
        "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.569.0",
        "@prisma/client": "^5.13.0",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
        "express": "^4.19.2",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
        "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
        "prisma": "^5.13.0",
        "sharp": "^0.33.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
        "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.7",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
        "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
        "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
        "typescript": "^5.4.5"
      }
    }

index.ts code
    import express, { Express, Request, Response } from "express";
    import cors from "cors";
    import dotenv from "dotenv";
    import postRouter from "./routes/post";
    import authRouter from "./routes/auth";
    import userRouter from "./routes/user";
    import messageRouter from "./routes/message";
    import chatRouter from "./routes/chat";
    import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
    
    dotenv.config();
    const app: Express = express();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8800; // process.env.PORT === 5000
    
    app.use(cors({ origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL, credentials: true }));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cookieParser());
    
    app.use("/api/posts", postRouter);
    app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);
    app.use("/api/users", userRouter);
    app.use("/api/chats", chatRouter);
    app.use("/api/messages", messageRouter);
    
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`[server]: Server is running at <https://localhost>:${PORT}`);
    });

This warning message occurred three times.
could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring types_hash_bucket_size
This is an error message.!!!
1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:(omit itself) , server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: (omit itself)
1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:(omit itself), server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host: (omit itself), referrer: (omit itself)
The service role and EC2 instance profile seem to be set up well.
When compressing the file, I tried including and excluding the node_modules folder.
Is there a problem with the port number?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am running out of time.TT

You are missing nodemon as a dependency in your package.json: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
}

